# How to compute time complexity of this algorithm (It has 6 lines Matlab code)

Tags: algorithm, performance, matlab, time

It's my code:

```
  image = imread ('imageFile.jpg');
  [m,n]=size(image);

  for i=1:m

      mask = image(i,:);
      Mean = mean(mask(:));
      stdm = std(mask(:));
      bwx(i,:) = ( mask > Mean*( 10 + k * ( stdm / r+10 )));

  end
```

I should compare this algorithm with another algorithm aspect of time. How can I compute time complexity of this algorithm?

r and k are constant.

**mean** and **std** are Matlab Functions.

mean = mean of each row of image.

std = standard deviation of each row of image.

Comment: The size of im is C columns X N rows. In each iteration of the for loop, you pull out a single row and examine that. So how many elements are you taking the mean of in each iteration? What is the time complexity for mean? Ditto for std dev.

Comment: Dear @TonyRuth , I edited my question, Hope u can help me.

Comment: I misread a part of the code in the beginning but changed my comment after I found the mistake. Try to answer the two questions in my comment and you will be well on the way to finding the time complexity of this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula for mean,

```html
<a href="http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=<s>=\frac&space;1&space;n&space;\sum&space;^n&space;_{i=0}&space;s_i" target="_blank"><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?<s>=\frac&space;1&space;n&space;\sum&space;^n&space;_{i=0}&space;s_i" title="<s>=\frac 1 n \sum ^n _{i=0} s_i" /></a>
```

If you count how many basic mathematical operations there are, addition, multiplication, subtraction, there are n total additions. So the time complexity of mean is O(n). That is mean is linear in time. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the complexity of std dev and the for loop in your code.

Comment: it's the formula of std, but what is the time complexity of that?  http://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=http://ncalculators.com/images/formulas/population-standard-deviation.jpg&imgrefurl=http://ncalculators.com/statistics/mean-standard-deviation-calculator.htm&h=136&w=298&tbnid=8duf3E5SaIdJ0M:&docid=ykbG664w8g1RkM&ei=gmY-VqHpKsKUsgH_uon4CQ&tbm=isch   , i don't know anything about that.

Comment: Karo, it comes down to how many basic mathematical operations there are. How many calculations do you need to do to evaluate the formula you linked?